# Bordism sanity check

Tags: differential-topology, math-history, cobordism

Were framed cobordism and h-cobordism invented to use for different purposes? I have been slightly confused about all the different types of cobordism. Now I am wondering if h-cobordism was invented as an alternative to classify manifolds whereas framed cobordism was invented to help determine homotopy groups of spheres. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty much correct.

Framed bordism was introduced by Pontryagin to study homotopy groups in the following paper:

> L. S. Pontryagin, *A classification of continuous transformations of a complex into a sphere*. Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR, 1938.

According to [Pontryagin's autobiography](http://ega-math.narod.ru/LSP/ch7.htm#a), he may have started working with this idea as early as 1936. Apparently Pontryagin (as well as Rokhlin) were only able to prove what is now known as the Pontryagin-Thom theorem in a few special cases. It wasn't until Thom's involvement that the Pontryagin-Thom construction as we know it today was developed and the Pontryagin-Thom theorem was proven in full.

The concept of $h$-cobordism was reportedly introduced by Thom in

> R. Thom, *Les classes caractéristiques de Pontryagin des variétés triangulées*. Symp. Internac. Topol. Algebr., Univ. Nac. Aut. Mexico & UNESCO, 1958.

I have never seen this paper and cannot find it anywhere, so I cannot comment on what it contains. The concept is discussed in detail in Milnor's paper:

> J. Milnor, [*Differentiable manifolds which are homotopy spheres*](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/homsph.pdf). 1959.

In the above paper, the term $h$-cobordism had not be introduced yet. Milnor calls it "$J$-equivalence" instead. Here Milnor utilizes $J$-equivalence/$h$-cobordism classes as a nice way to categorize manifolds and studies the group of $J$-equivalence/$h$-cobordism classes of homotopy spheres. Note that here Milnor anticipates (although without all the necessary hypotheses: he asks if $J$-equivalent/$h$-cobordant *not necessarily simply connected* manifolds are diffeomorphic) the $h$-cobordism theorem (Problem 5 in $\S$7). Milnor gives a counterexample to Problem 5 in

> J. Milnor, [*Two complexes which are homeomorphic but combinatorially distinct*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970299). The Annals of Mathematics, 74(3), 1961.

Here one sees that by 1963 the term "$J$-equivalent" has been replaced by the modern "$h$-cobordant."

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Thom's paper is available here https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/mexico.pdf. The definition of _Variétés J-équivalentes_ is on page 58.